# Python (discord.py) How to identify whether a message sent is an embed message or just regular text?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

For example code that would return **true** for an embed menu posted by another bot, and **false** for if the bot just sends a simple text message.

Answer (score 0):

Well For That All u need to do is

```
async def on_message(message):
  if message.embed:
     print("The MSG Is Embed")
```

Ref: [Discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)

Hope This Helps if it doesn't then ping me